# (mis) understanding priors in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm new to this package; I usually use Stan for Bayesian models, but I'm using a lot of data and hoping I can get the models to run faster in MCMCglmm. I have read the course notes as well as the [readme on github](https://github.com/tmalsburg/MCMCglmm-intro). They are really helpful and great descriptions, but I still do not understand how to set priors.

I have a simple mixed effects model, and here is some example code. (I know that others have asked this question, but I had trouble finding one with reproducible code and those answers helped users with a specific question, while I'm trying to understand what the values in a prior list mean).

```
library(MCMCglmm)
# inverse logit function for simulation
inv.logit <- function(x){
  exp(x)/(exp(x)+1)
}
# simulate some data
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
covariates <- replicate(3, rnorm(n, 0, .5))
X <- cbind(rep(1, length(covariates[,1])),covariates)
colnames(X) <- c('int', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3')
coefs <- c(1, -1, -.5, 0.3)
resp <- X %*% coefs
psi <- inv.logit(resp)
ind <- rep(1:10, floor(n/10)) # assigning individuals for random effect, but it's not important
n_inds <- length(unique(ind))
y <- rbinom(n, 1, psi)
df <- data.frame(ind, y, X)

# priors: I really don't know what I'm doing here
prior1 <- list(R = list(V = 2, n = 1, fix=1),
               G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(3), n = 3)))

# run the model
glmm <- MCMCglmm(y ~ X1 + X2 + X3,
                 random= ~ us(1 + ind), # having random slope and random intercept for ind
                 family = "categorical",
                 data = df,
                 prior=prior1
                 )
```

If I were running this in Stan, I would set priors for each fixed effect covariate: Beta ~ normal(0, sigma_beta) and the hyperprior: sigma_beta ~ gamma(2,1). (Although, I'd also be happy just setting the prior as Beta ~ normal(0,100) or something like this.) I would use similar priors for the random effects. I understand that MCMCglmm is more limited in distributions, but I really don't understand the notation. To be clear, I'm not really interested in specifying priors in this example model, I'm trying to understand how one does it.

Is there somewhere I can find a definition of what is exactly meant by each of the values that goes into the prior (e.g., V, n, alpha, ...) and how these values correspond to what we would write in a full model description of the priors? Or is someone willing to explain it to more simple minded people like me? The descriptions in the course notes and github were not able to answer my question.
Thank you!

Comment: MCMCglmm makes heavy use of the inverse Wishart prior. `?MCMCglmm` defines the parameters under `prior`. There isn't much else than the course notes and the [JSS paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v033i02).

Comment: E.g. the paper says: _"For non-parameter expanded models, the parameter (co)variance matrices are assumed to have (conditional) inverse-Wishart prior distributions and individual elements for each component of the variance structure take the arguments V, n and fix which specify the expected (co)variance matrix at the limit, the degree of freedom parameter, and the partition to condition on."_